# window.open not working in iphone at the time of document ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

window.open not working in iphone at the time of document ready event

I have write the code to open the new windows at the time of page load event. this event working fine in evenry browser instead of iphone(Safari). now i dont know what the alternative way to do this?

please help me to solve this issue.

```
 OpenWindow('http://www.google.com', 800, 600, true);    

function OpenWindow(query, w, h, scroll) {
    var l = (screen.width - w) / 2;
    var t = (screen.height - h) / 2;

    winprops = 'resizable=1, height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top=' + t + ',left=' + l + 'w';
    if (scroll) winprops += ',scrollbars=1';
       var f = window.open(query, "_blank", winprops);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround

```
<script> 
document.write("<a id='mylink' href='mypage.html'></a>");
document.getElementById('mylink').click();
</script>
```

or

```
<body onload="myfunct('mylink')">
```

and declare the function as above

Comment: This is standard javascript. Are you saying that no browser can fire .click() event?